# Opposite of 'park' : to leave vehicle in place

Tags: verbs, synonyms

What's the name of the procedure reverse of parking?

To park a car is to guide it from the road into a parking spot and then stop the engine.

To ____ a car is to start the engine, and reverse it out of the parking spot onto the road so it's ready to drive.

Comment: My instinctual thought is "to drive out" or "reverse out"

Comment: Can I assume that you have a particular word in your language for this, and you have looked for this word in bilingual dictionary.

Comment: @JamesK I am english first language, and looked up park in a thesaurus and couldn't find anything

Comment: How about “take the car out”?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any transitive verb that fits this context.

Typically people would talk about ** to get under way** or ** to proceed**.

An instructor might say **to start/begin** or **the first thing to do** (which, I'm aware are not direct answers to your question).

Comment: Agreed. I know we use the word more widely, but basically you _park_ your car when you 'store' it in a designated place when it's away from home but not in use. So the converse is to _set off for home, leave the car park_ or whatever fits the circumstances. regardless of the exact manoeuvres you might have to make.